# send mail in java without javax.mail

Tags: java, email, apache-commons-email

Ok so is there any other library in java for sending emails?

I tried to use `javax.mail` and `commons-email` and I keep getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-645" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Method not yet implemented
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.<init>(MimeMessage.java:89)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.buildMimeMessage(Email.java:1011)
    at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1162)
    at com.liveratesfeeds.tss.email.SendEmail.sendWarningEmail(SendEmail.java:62)
```

Comment: What version of JavaMail are you using?  And if you haven’t already, please edit your question and show the *entire* stack trace, including any `Caused by` sections.

Comment: What functionality do you try to use? Can you post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve please?

Answer (score 0):

you need to external libraries:

1) javax.mail
2) activation.jar

Comment: I see all the Java email tutorials on sending emails use both of these but never fully understood why the activation.jar is a necessity, if anyone could provide insight on this it'd be appreciated